# Running Java 9 jshell in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jshell

How can I run Java 9 jshell in Eclipse? I want to easily run simple snippets of code directly in Eclipse IDE.
I already tried to run jshell as an 'External Tool' configuration in Eclipse but when typing a command I don't get any response back.